# Is it possible to make cross browser compatible games with Dart as of right now?

Tags: dart

What about just making it compatible with the three major browsers, IE9+, Chrome and Firefox?

I want to make games using Canvas 2D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, it works just fine. Unfortunately, I can't test it out right now because I don't have a Windows machine. However, there are a lot of samples showing how to do this sort of thing. See:

- http://dart-lang.github.com/pop-pop-win/
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pop-pop-win
- https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-html5-samples/tree/master/web/speed/animations

Canvas is supported by modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: I have had no issues with Canvas or Dart on Windows. I also see no reason why games wouldn't work across modern browsers.